# How to find Profit percent in this case?

Tags: finance

A trader allows a discount of 20% on his goods and still makes a profit of 25%.Find the profit percent made, if he sells his goods at:
(1) the Marker price
(2) at 10% discount

What i've tried:

```
let MP = 100
D=20%
=> SP = 80

SP = 80
P = 25%

SP      CP
125     100
80       ?

CP = (80 * 100)/125
   = 64

profit = SP - CP 
       = 80 - 64
       = 16

P% = 16/64 * 100  
   = 25%
```

---

but the correct answer is 56.25 %

Comment: Is this an Icse board question? Cause copper hat's method is not allowed for board.

Comment: Yes it is. By the way- don't post queries as answers, use comments for those sorts of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S$ be the usual sale price, $C$ be the cost.

You are given that $\frac{0.8 S } { C} = 1.25$.

For (1), you want to compute $\frac{S } { C} = \frac{1} {0.8} \frac{0.8 S } { C} = \frac{1} { 0.8} 1.25 = 1.5625$ (ie, 56.25%).

For (2), you want to compute $\frac{0.9 S } { C} = 0.9 \cdot 1.5625 = 1.40625$ (ie, 40.625%).

Comment: i didn't understand the 3rd line, why's it 1/0.8 ?

Comment: Divide both sides of the equation on Line 2 by 0.8. (A 20% reduction corresponds to a sales price of $0.8S$.)